# Qnit and OPA testing in SAP UI5

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, qunit, sapui5

I wanted to learn unit and integration testing in SAP UI5, but even after reading the documentations many things are unclear like

1. what are we doing with sinon stub?
2. How can we test controllers in Qunit?
3. How OPA testing works

If anyone can explain with examples that would be really helpful.

Regards,
Raju

Answer (score 2):

Try to work through the [Testing tutorial](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/291c9121e6044ab381e0b51716f97f52) it will teach you the most important concept.
After that play around with Test following this [blog about automated testing](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/05/21/automated-testing-for-sap-fiori-apps-piece-of-cake-with-sap-web-ide-and-the-sapui5-testing-tools/)

But to answer your questions:

1. Sinon stubs help you for example to "mock" your call to the backend. In an automated testing scenario you don't want to fail only because the backend is not reachable. (You want to test you app, not the backend)
2. You don't test controller in QUnit, you test functions. For example formatters. To check the correctness of your controller, you usually use OPA Tests, because most controller functions depend on the corresponding view (e.g. onPress-function of a Button)
3. Take a look at the OPA tests in the Demo App like [Master Detail](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/6256083b146e40b896309ead6ccd8751). In general OPA tests start the App and fill field or press buttons via code.